# attribute error in retrieval of text

Tags: python, tkinter

After making progress in my coursework I have hit another roadblock in the fact that there is an attribute error which I am unable to resolve. I am trying to retrieve the information that the user has input for their account credentials so that the data can be compared to the information in the database I have and the user can be granted or denied access to the account i.e. a login screen.
The error is:

`AttributeError: 'LogInScreen' object has no attribute 'usernameEntry'`

And the code where this comes from is:

```
class LogInScreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        description = tk.Label(self, text="Please log in to gain access to the content of this computer science program.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        description.pack()

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Enter your username:")
        label1.pack()

        usernameEntry = tk.Entry(self)
        usernameEntry.pack()

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Enter your password:")
        label2.pack()


        passwordEntry = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        passwordEntry.pack()

        notRecognised=tk.Label(self, text="")

        logInButton = tk.Button(self, text="Log In",
                                command=self.logUserIn)
        logInButton.pack()

        self.controller = controller

    def logUserIn(self):
        username = self.usernameEntry.get()
        password = self.passwordEntry.get()

        find_user = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username == ? AND password == ?")
        cursor.execute(find_user,[(username),(password)])
        results = cursor.fetchall()
```

I'm not sure as to why I'm getting the error and i have asked other people in my class for help but I'm not getting very far. I'm aware it's probably something very simple but i cant resolve it myself. Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue from this error `AttributeError: 'LogInScreen' object has no attribute 'usernameEntry'` is due to the fact that you have not defined `usernameEntry` as a class attribute. So when you program initializes it will create the widgets but nothing will be able to interact with it from outside of `__init__`.

If a method within the class needs to interact with the variables outside of the method or to interact from outside of your class instance the variables need to be assigned as an attribute with the prefix `self.`

All you need to do is change this:

```
usernameEntry = tk.Entry(self)
usernameEntry.pack()

passwordEntry = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
passwordEntry.pack()
```

To this:

```
self.usernameEntry = tk.Entry(self)
self.usernameEntry.pack()

self.passwordEntry = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
self.passwordEntry.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

In method `logUserIn(self)` you try to access an attribute `self.usernameEntry` which is not defined.

In `__init__()` you have a variable named `usernameEntry`, but this variable is not an attribute. Maybe you want to add `self.usernameEntry = usernameEntry` to the `__init__` method to turn that variable into an attribute which will then be accessible by `logUserIn`?

BTW it will be the same for `passwordEntry`.

Comment: why would you do `self.usernameEntry = usernameEntry`? All you need to do is add `self.` as the prefix of `usernameEntry` There is no point in assigning it the way you have suggested.

Comment: I don't think telling someone to do something that is considered bad practice is a good way to teach something. You are saying to make `usernameEntry` a class attribute you need to do `self.usernameEntry = usernameEntry` this is misleading and not accurate. The OP will think they need to do this for all class attributes and it goes against the DRY method of coding and is an extra step that is not needed.